# wpf- How to wait for result from Dispatcher.invokeAsync before control is passed to next statement

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Lazy method in which I have called Dispacter

```
private Lazy<ObservableCollection<WidgetTasksSummary>> LazyTasksSummaryHelper()
{
    return new Lazy<ObservableCollection<WidgetTasksSummary>>(() =>
    {
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => GetActivityItemsCount());
        return new ObservableCollection<WidgetTasksSummary>(GetMyTasksSummary());
    });
}
private ActivitySearchResultList ActivityItemsCount{get;set;}
private ObservableCollection<WidgetTasksSummary> GetMyTasksSummary()
{
        //Do Something
}
private async Task GetActivityItemsCount()
{
    try
    {
        ActivityItemsCount = await Ioc.Resolve<IServiceCall>().InvokeAsync<IActivityManager, ActivitySearchResultList>(this.MakeWeakFunc<IActivityManager, ActivitySearchResultList>((service) =>
           service.GetActivityCounts(activityFilter)));
    }
}
```

I am using **ActivityItemsCount** Property to assign result of api call.
After LazyTasksHelper is called, the control is sent to **GetMyTasksSummary()** after **dispacter**.
I want to wait for the dispacter to make api call and store result in property. And then continue execution.
I am using the property in getTasksSummary. **So, I need it to be filled first in action called in dispacter then enter into method GetMyTasksSummary()**

Comment: GetActivityItemsCount is running on the UI thread, which you probably don't want.

Comment: Are you sure you need the Dispatcher here?

Comment: Your question is too broad and unclear. But the biggest odd thing is, if you want to **wait** for the invocation to complete, why aren't you calling `Invoke()` instead of `InvokeAsync()`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Even if we use Invoke, the control moves to next line before filling the data into property. In api call I have used InvokeAsync and I don't want to alter that

Comment: @Yevgeniy If I dont use Dispatcher, I need to use AyncLazy. I dont want to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to [`AsyncLazy`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLazy) and `await` that call.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I moved all the api calls and other stuffs into another ViewModel and used `Lazy<ViewModel>`. In this way, viewmodel takes care of calling api and setting up necessary property.